# Explicit generators for matrix invariants of the symmetric group

Tags: invariant-theory

Let $V$ be the space of $n$ by $n$ complex matrices with the conjugate  action of the symmetric group $G=S_n$. Is any explicit set of generators for the invariant ring $C[V]^G$ known?

Comment: I've merged your accounts.  If you register, you won't need to worry about making new user ids.

Answer (score 5):

For a related question, invariants of the action of $G$ on the space of pairs of {1,...,n}, (this is a quotient ring of $C[V]^{G}$) see Sect. 2 of [Algebraic invariants of graphs; a study based on computer exploration, by Nicolas M. Thiéry](http://arxiv.org/abs/0812.3082). However, the generating set given there is certainly very far from a minimal, and degrees are high. Sect. 10 of this paper also discusses the ring you are asking about.

Comment: @Dima: excellent reference. It seems to me that the ring in Ketan's question is exactly the Grigoriev digraph invariant ring mentioned in Section 10 of Thiery's article.

Answer (score 3):

thanks for all the answers. I found a paper by Garcia and Stanton, "Group actions on 
Stanley Reisner rings and .." (Advances in Maths, 1984), which provides a reasonable answer to this
question.

Ketan Mulmuley

Comment: Are you your own evil twin? There seem to be two KMs with different reps...